# Is it possible to determine how an iOS app was opened?

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Is it possible for an iOS app (for example in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`) to determine *how* or *from where* it was opened. In particular, if the app was opened by another app using a URL scheme, is it possible to get the information about the app that triggered the opening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this method in the ApplicationDelegate protocol:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

This is what is called when another application tries to open your app with a custom url scheme. According to the docs....

> Your implementation of this method should open the specified URL and
>   update its user interface accordingly.

but you also get a little information about the caller as well.